# Sybase JZ0R2 issue related to connection pool refresh on Weblogic

Tags: spring, weblogic, sybase

We have application running on weblogic . At times ( once in 2-3 weeks ) all of the sudden I start getting below in stack trace. Even after multiple try I only get "JZ0R2: No result set for this query" but data is there in DB for the row. And to resolve I simply refresh weblogic connection pools and things start working as expected. Can someone help with any tentative reason for this behavior.

DB : Sybase DB version 15.7
Java: 1.7

Error retrieving database meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: JZ0R2: No result set for this query.
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Error retrieving database meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: JZ0R2: No result set for this query.
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataProviderFactory.createMetaDataProvider(CallMetaDataProviderFactory.java:142)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataContext.initializeMetaData(CallMetaDataContext.java:243)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.compileInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:304)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.compile(AbstractJdbcCall.java:289)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.checkCompiled(AbstractJdbcCall.java:349)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:364)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:197)

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

```
conn.setAutoCommit( true );
```

or set various isolation levels, like this one, for instance:

```
conn.setTransactionIsolation(0);
```